# (python) Iterating through a list of Salesforce tables to extract and load into AWS S3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

Good Morning All!

I'm trying to have a routine iterate through a table list.  The below code works on a single table 'contact'.  I want to iterate through all of the tables listed  in my tablelist.csv.  I bolded the selections below which would need to be dynamically modified in the code.  My brain is pretty fried at this point from working through two nights and I'm fully prepared for the internet to tell me that this is in chapter two of intro to Python but I could use the help just to get over this hurdle.

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3
from simple_salesforce import salesforce

li = pd.read_csv('tablelist.csv', header=none)
desc = sf.**Contact**.describe()  
field_names = [field['name'] for field in desc['fields']]
soql = "SELECT {} FROM **Contact**".format(','.join(field_names))
results = sf.query_all(soql)
sf_df = pd.DataFrame(results['records']).drop(columns='attributes')
sf_df.to_csv('**contact**.csv')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file('contact.csv', 'mybucket', 'Ops/20201027/contact.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would help if you could provide a sample of the tablelist file, but here's a stab at...you really just need to get list of tables and loop through it.

```
#assuming table is a column somewhere in the file
df_tablelist = pd.read_csv('tablelist.csv', header=none)
for Contact in df_tablelist['yourtablecolumttoiterateon'].tolist():
    desc = sf.**Contact**.describe()  
    field_names = [field['name'] for field in desc['fields']]
    soql = "SELECT {} FROM {}".format(','.join(field_names), Contact)
    results = sf.query_all(soql)
    sf_df = pd.DataFrame(results['records']).drop(columns='attributes')
    sf_df.to_csv(Contact + '.csv')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file(Contact + '.csv', 'mybucket', 'Ops/20201027/' + Contact + '.csv')
```